# When extending a asp.net web control, at which event should additional web controls be injected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-controls

I'm trying to avoid a composite control or using and ASCX by extending an existing control. However, I'm having trouble with getting the controls added to the inherited control and keep their view-state/post-back integrity. Whenever I add the controls during pre-render, the controls show up, but the post-back throws a viewstate exception.  I tried adding them both there and during LoadViewState (which of course was a long-shot silly).  Init is not available from the control which I'm extending.

> The exception is
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Failed to load viewsstate. The control
>   tree into which viewstate is being
>   loaded must match the control tree
>   that was used to save viewstate during
>   the previous request.  For example,
>   when adding controls dynamically, the
>   controls added during a post-back must
>   match the type and position of the
>   controls added during the initial
>   request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, microsoft says you should override the [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) method.

You can call the base class method before or after you add the controls, I'm not sure if there is a convention there.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls(){
  Controls.Add(someControl);
  base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You should add them in OnInit or in CreateChildControls. Anyway, to avoid having troubles with ViewState, read [this GREAT article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx). Possibly, sample "4. Initializing child controls programmatically" is your case.

Comment: I read that article a year ago, lost the link, and have been looking for it again ever since. Thanks for posting it here.  If I could upvote twice I would.